# Inconsistent behaviour between NumPy floats and integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization, numpy-ndarray

Consider the following code

```
# Create the 5x3 array
array1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [101, 110, 120], [13, 14, 15]])

# Create the 8x3 array 
array2 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6], [16, 17, 18], [19, 20, 21], [10, 11, 12], [22, 23, 24], [13, 14, 15]])

# Check equality of each element in array1 with every element in array2
result = np.any(array1[:, None] == array2, axis=2)

# Convert the resulting matrix to an nx1 Boolean matrix
final_result = np.squeeze(np.any(result, axis=1, keepdims=True))
```

This code behaves exactly as expected and outputs the following

```
[ True  True  True False  True]
```

However, when I try the same thing with an array of floats, the behaviour is different.

```
array3 = np.array([[90., -40.8 , -1.35],[0., 0., -1.35],[0., 0.,-1.35], [100., 0.,-1.35], [-10., 50.8,-1.35], [100., -50.8,5.], [ 29.5, 0., 5.  ],[ -2.89, -50.8,-1.35], [0., 0.,0.], [0., 0.,0.], [0., 0.,0.], [0., 0.,0.], [0., 0.,0.]], dtype=float)

array4 = np.array([[90, -50.8, -1.35], [90, -50.8, 5], [90, -50.8, -1.35], [-10, 50.8, -1.35], [-10, 50.8, 5], [90, -50.8, 5]], dtype=float)

# Check equality of each element in array4 with every element in array4
result = np.any(array4[:, None] == array3, axis=2)

# Convert the resulting matrix to an nx1 Boolean matrix
final_result = np.squeeze(np.any(result, axis=1, keepdims=True))
```

This outputs

```
[ True  True  True  True  True  True]
```

This is wrong because only the element at `array[3]` should be `True` while all others should be `False`. When printing out `result` I can see the following

```
[[ True  True  True  True  True  True False  True False False False False
  False]
 [ True False False False False  True  True  True False False False False
  False]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True False  True False False False False
  False]
 [ True  True  True  True  True False False  True False False False False
  False]
 [False False False False  True  True  True False False False False False
  False]
 [ True False False False False  True  True  True False False False False
  False]]
```

And from here I can infer that when at least one element of the array matches with the other, the output is `True`. How can I modify the code so that a `True` is returned only if all the elements in the array equal all the elements of the other array?

The expected output must be the size of `array4` and look as follows

```
[False False False True False False
```

Comment: "How can I modify the code so that a True is returned only if all the elements in the array equal all the elements of the other array?" - if you wanted to make sure *all* elements were equal, why did you use `any`?

Comment: Is this definitely an int vs float difference? The difference between the two examples isn't only between int vs float: it's that in example 1, every pair of arrays has either 3 matching elements or 0 matching elements. But in example 2 there are pairs with 1 or 2 matching elements.

Comment: @user2357112, yes you're right, I just caught that moments before this comment and I'm actually really close to solving this now :)

Comment: For example, in the first example, what happens if you put an extra subarray `([101, 999, 999])` into `array2`?

Comment: @slothrop you're absolutely right. I should've used `np.all()` instead of `np.any()`. I have it working now and have answered the question so that it can be closed. Thanks for the input :)

Comment: beware of equality tests of floats

Answer (score 0):

Turns out using `np.any()` was the culprit and `NumPy` was doing exactly what it was supposed to irrespective of the input being an array of `floats` or `ints`. Modifying the code as follows

```
result = np.all(array4[:, None] == array3, axis=2)
final_result = np.any(result, axis=1)
```

Gives me my desired output of `[False False False  True False False]`

Shoutout to @user2357112 and @slothrop for the hints. The above can also be done using `np.islcose()` and is the better way to do it

```
result = np.all(np.isclose(array4[:, None], array3, atol=1e-8), axis=2)
final_result = np.any(result, axis=1)
```

Comment: By the way, why are you using `keepdims` if you don't want to keep the dimension?

Comment: @user2357112 Thank you for pointing out that needless exercise. I'm still getting the hang of `NumPy` so I ended up over complicating things. Have edited the answer accordingly.